# Bash should not count color codes as visible characters

Tags: bash

I'm using `fold` to wrap my input file. I noticed that some colored lines are shorter.
I found that `bash` counts color codes as characters, even if there are not visible.
Example:

```
$ text="\e[0;31mhello\e[0m"; echo -e "$text - lenght ${#text}"
hello - lenght 18
$ text="hello"; echo -e "$text - lenght ${#text}"
hello - lenght 5
```

This happens for other non visible characters also:

```
$ text="a\bb\bc"; echo -e "$text - lenght ${#text}"
c - lenght 7
```

Is it possible to change this behavior? I would like that `coreutils` programs (`bash` and `fold` for example) could count only the visible characters.

Comment: This is why `bash` provides the `\[` and `\]` pairs for its various prompt strings. Without them, `bash` would not know that escape codes to modify, e.g., colors should not count towards the length of the prompt as displayed on your screen. Unfortunately, they (and other prompt escapes) don't have any special meaning outside of the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete solution for your problem, but it's important to know that bash doesn't handle escape sequences in literals.

So `"\b"` is really 2 characters, `\` and `b`. Only when you `echo -e`, *then* they are substituted.

Example:

```
text="a\bb\bc"
t=$(echo -e $text)
echo ${#t}
5  # the correct length
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically it's all demanded to the single program?

Comment: Sry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant: I can't change the Bash behavior, I should try to change how the various programs manage the substitution, right?

Comment: If you feed them with `echo -e`, they don't have to do substition. The problem is, some of the tools (eg: `fold`) don't recognise the terminal escape sequences (eg: coloring).

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect, but you can remove the format bytes with a tool like `sed` before counting.

```
text="\e[0;31mhello\e[0m";
echo -e "# $text - lenght ${#text}";
# hello - lenght 18
x=$(echo -e "$text" | sed "s/$(echo -e "\e")[^m]*m//g");
echo "# $x - ${#x}"
# hello - 5
```